# Como pegar parâmetro passado na função e pegar na mesma função no react-native?

Tags: react-native

Olá

Quero passar um valor por uma função em um `touchableOpacity` e pegar esse valor, dentro da função, como devo proceder?

Segue meus códigos:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class Categorias extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      cidade: null,
      tipo: "",
    };
  }

  procurar(){
    let cidade = this.state.cidade;
    let tipo = this.state.tipo;
    let opcao = 'procurar estabelecimentos';
    console.log(`${cidade} - ${tipo} - ${opcao}`)
    var urlProcurar = endpoint.backendUrl + 'app/procurarEstabelecimento.php?cidade=' + cidade + '&opcao=' + opcao + '&tipo=' + tipo;
    fetch(urlProcurar,{ method: 'GET'})
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        this.setState({estabelecimento: responseJson});

    })
       .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);

       });
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{marginBottom:20}}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.textoCategorias}>Categorias</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputProcurarCidade}
                    placeholder="Cidade"
                    onChangeText={texto => this.state.cidade = texto}
                />
            </View>


        </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginBottom:20}} onPress={ ()=>{ this.procurar() && this.setState({tipo: "Restaurante"}) } }>
              <ImageBackground style={styles.restaurante} source={restaurantes}>
              <Text style={styles.textoRestaurante} >R E S T A U R A N T E S</Text>
              </ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>


      </View>
    );
  }
}


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui...

No botão faço:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{marginBottom:20}} onPress={ ()=>{ this.procurar('Restaurante') } }>
```

E não função:

```
 procurar(arg){
   let cidade = this.state.cidade;
   let opcao = 'procurar estabelecimentos';
   console.log(`${cidade} - ${arg} - ${opcao}`)
 }
```